# Having the database, calculate current salary for each employee if salary increases every 6 month according to the following rates for the positions

Tags: sql

Having the database, calculate current salary for each employee if salary increases every 6 month according to the following rates for the positions

Comment: What have you tried so far? Generally we ask that you include your schema and DBMS so we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this (using sql server, you don't talk about your db engine... not tested)

```
select
  *,
  case when datediff(month, date_start, getdate()) < 6
    or position not in ('data analys intern','accountant','marketing manager','support specialist')
    then base_salary
    else 
      base_salary * datediff(month, date_start, getdate()) % 6
      case position 
        when 'data analys intern' then 1.8 
        when 'accountant' then 1.3
        when 'marketing manager' then 1.5
        when 'support specialist' then 1.6
      end
  end as newSalary
from your_database
```

Comment: @arararararar, can you please upvote and mark as correct the answer if it is correct for your question? Thank you!